# Removing values not between 1910 - 2015 in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Here is my code that should do what the title says (from row 3) but it doesn't work. Does anyone why it is not working? The numbers in the columns are formatted as text. Thanks

```
        Dim i As Long
   For i = 3 To lastRow

      If Not (wsFinal.Cells(i, "Q").Value <= 2015 Or wsFinal.Cells(i, "Q").Value >= 1910) Then
        With wsFinal
            .Cells(i, "Q").ClearContents
        End With

      End If
   Next i

   Dim j As Long
      For j = 3 To lastRow

      If Not (wsFinal.Cells(j, "R").Value <= 2015 Or wsFinal.Cells(j, "R").Value >= 1910) Then
        With wsFinal
            .Cells(j, "R").ClearContents
        End With

      End If

   Next j
```

Comment: What is the error message/ your output?

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is wrong.

`(wsFinal.Cells(i, "Q").Value <= 2015 Or wsFinal.Cells(i, "Q").Value >= 1910)`

1909 returns `True` and 1910 returns `True`. You need to change `Or` to `And`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to fix the logic so it's a bit more clear. You could make a truth table to determine if a value would go into the if statement.

```
        <=2015  >=1910  OR      Not
1900    TRUE    FALSE   TRUE    FALSE
2000    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    FALSE
2100    FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    FALSE

        <=2015  >=1910  AND     Not
1900    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   TRUE
2000    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    FALSE
2100    FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   TRUE
```

As a personal style, I prefer to make it so if the value is outside the range (as shown below) then perform the action rather than using the `Not` keyword and potentially adding confusion while reading.

```
        >2015   <1910   OR
1900    FALSE   TRUE    TRUE
2000    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
2100    TRUE    FALSE   TRUE
```

Other personal suggestions for keeping code easier to debug:

- if you only have one line within a `with` statement, then don't use the `with`.
- If you are only performing one action in an if statement then the one line shortcut proves to be quite nice `if <cond> then <action>`
- If you have two loops that do the same thing, you don't need to have two counters. You can reused them. Or if the actions can be performed at the same time, you can group them.

The code below works for me even when the columns were formatted as text.

```
Dim wsFinal As Worksheet, LastRow As Integer
Set wsFinal = ActiveSheet
LastRow = wsFinal.UsedRange.Rows.count

For i = 3 To LastRow
    If (wsFinal.Cells(i, "Q").value > 2015 Or wsFinal.Cells(i, "Q").value < 1910) Then wsFinal.Cells(i, "Q").ClearContents
    If (wsFinal.Cells(i, "R").value > 2015 Or wsFinal.Cells(i, "R").value < 1910) Then wsFinal.Cells(i, "R").ClearContents
Next i
```